# Variation of a vertical component

Tags: homework-and-exercises, velocity

Any ideas on what it means to 'describe and explain the variation of the vertical component of the ball as it travels towards the ground'?
[image]

I dont need answers but instead a way of answering (answers wouldnt go amiss tho)
(A-Level Question)
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand, its asking about the vertical motion of the ball, so ignore the 2m/s sideways velocity, and focus your answer on how it falls (acceleration under gravity)